# proof: $\bigcap_{j=1}^n(A_{1j}\cup A_{2j})=\bigcup_{(j_1,j_2,...,j_n)\in\{1,2\}^n}(A_{j_11}\cap A_{j_22}\cap...A_{j_nn})$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider the sample space $\Omega=(0,1]$ and subsets of the space of the form $(a,b]$ with $0<a\le b\le1$.
$$\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^n(a_j,b_j]\right)^c=\bigcap_{j=1}^n(a_j,b_j]^c=\bigcap_{j=1}^n\left(0,a_j]\cup(b_j,1]\right)=:\bigcap_{j=1}^n(A_{1j}\cup A_{2j})\\=\bigcup_{(j_1,j_2,...,j_n)\in\{1,2\}^n}(A_{j_11}\cap A_{j_22}\cap...A_{j_nn}).$$
I do understand how the last step came to be and it is easy to see if I only consider $j=1,2$. However, extension of it to $n$, I can't figure how to prove the last step notationally. Visually it makes sense as for every $j=1,2,...n$, $A_{1j}$'s intersection with the all other $A_{ij}$'s need to be included (except for its intersection with $A_{2j}$.

I am looking for an extra step before the final equality, basically even though I do understand how it happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you can prove this by induction on $n$, and it shouldn't be too difficult.

Another approach is to notice that this is a particular case of the *complete distributivity* of powersets.
See [Examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_distributive_lattice#Examples) of completely distributive lattices.

This law states that
$$\bigwedge_{i\in I}\bigvee_{j\in J}x_{ij} = \bigvee_{f:I\to J}\bigwedge_{i\in I}x_{i,f(i)}.$$
In your case, $\wedge$ is set intersection, $\vee$ is set union, $I=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and $J=\{1,2\}$.